# How to disable drive toast notification (Scan and Fix Removable Disk)?

Tags: windows-8, notifications, popups

Windows 8 keeps popping up this toast notifications

I tried to disable them by menu, group policy, stopped the shell hardware detection and set following registry keys:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications" /v NoToastApplicationNotification /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v ShowInfoTip /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v FolderContentsInfoTip /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v StartButtonBalloonTip /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v EnableBalloonTips /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Nevertheless this toast is popping up

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KivU6.png]

It says there is a problem with the drive and leads me to 'Scan and Fix Removable Disk'

How can i disable this toast notification permanently?

The value `ToastEnabled` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications` is set to `0`.

Comment: Do you fix your car by putting tape over the Check Engine light?  Instead of disabling the warning, why not try to fix your drive?

Comment: thanks for your reply, but the problem is the toast notification. at this pc there will run an application and i have to take into consideration users with broken usb drives will use it.